# rtabmap with depth only sensors

Tags: slam, navigation, sensor, rtabmap, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I am trying to implement SLAM with depth only camera - Occipitals Structure sensor. I use openni2  launch for getting the camera msgs on ROS. I was wondering if I could use RTABmapping with this sensor or is the RGB camera needed ?

I have used Kinect with RTAB mapping and it worked fine. But Kinect is too big for my application and Structure sensor has internal battery as well, which works great for portability.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200039/rtabmap-with-depth-only-sensors/) by [VijethRai](https://answers.ros.org/users/21212/vijethrai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-12-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-12-24**:
rtabmap requires rgb info

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-05-18**:
Am unable to get output. Can you plz tell the any changes required before running launch file.
I am connecting Kinect and running launch file, Nothing is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A RGB stream registered to the depth stream is required. I’m pretty sure that the [Structure](http://structure.io/) sensor can register the depth image with the RGB image from the camera of the iPad.

You may want to look at the [Asus Xtion live Pro](http://www.asus.com/ca-en/Multimedia/Xtion_PRO_LIVE/) for a more compact design of the Kinect. The Asus is powered by USB too!

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2015-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3